# How to call nested react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Objective:** When my Game component receives a prop I want `componentDidUpdate()` to call a function called `consolelog` which is a child of another function called `gamecode()`.

**Problem:** using `this.gameCode.consolelog()` always returns an error saying that `consolelog` is not a function of `gameCode`.

**Note:** `Gamecode()` is imported into my react component (Game) from a file called `gamecode.js`

**Component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {gameCode, showLeaderboard} from '../utility/gamecode';

class Game extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {
      drawL : null
    }
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.gameCode();
  };

  componentDidUpdate(){
    //will run when the state changes
    if(this.props.leaderboard){
        var a = this.props.leaderboard;
        this.gameCode.consolelog(a);
    }
  }   

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="Game">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <button onClick={this.props.getleaderboard} className="showleaders">Show leaderboard</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Game;
```

**GameCode.js function:**

```
gameCode(){
  //the main function initializes some stuff immediately and start running the update() and draw() functions
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = 800;
  canvas.height= 600;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const FPS = 30;
  setInterval(() => {
      update();
      draw();
  }, 1000/FPS);

  //but sometimes I need to call other functions on demand, but these functions depend on what the parent function and other sibling functions
  function consolelog(a){
    console.log("success!");
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why "a child of another function"? Why can't you just export `consolelog` as its own function, and import it into your module?

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is because I have other subfunctions that rely on variables/functions that are scoped to `GameCode()`.

This is a canvas html game and so I have subfunctions called `update` and `draw` that draw to the canvas and I don't want multiple functions drawing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something along the lines of a [revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript). Keep private variables in scope to `gameCode` and export the public vars and functions that you need.

```
const gameCode = (function () {

  const a = 1;

  function consolelog() {
    console.log(`success${a}`);
  }

  return {
    consolelog: consolelog
  }

});

export default gameCode;
```

In your other file:

```
import gameCode from './gameCode';

componentDidMount() {
  const gc = gameCode();
  gc.consolelog(); // success1
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/64a4vobk/2/)**

Comment: all my consts and variables come back as undefined when I use your method, but only when I wrap the `const a = 1` in an init function

Comment: You don't need to put it in an init function. What's the reason for doing so?

Comment: Well for some reason when I don't put it into an init function,the `canvas` const that I define one line above `canvas.width = 800;` shows up as undefined... not sure why querySelector can no longer find it.

Comment: ahh I figured out what was causing the bug. The () at the end of the gamecode.js file was causing it to run as soon as I imported it which was before the canvas rendered.

Comment: So the problem is that if I remove the () then I cannot call `gameCode.consolelog()` but if I don't remove it then `querySelectory` cannot find the `canvas` element

Comment: Try removing it but in your component call `gameCode().consolelog` instead. I think I know the reason why, but you might as well check before I change my answer.

Comment: @Badrush, I checked - it worked. It didn't work originally because it was initialising when it was imported when the component hadn't rendered. Calling it later works properly.

Comment: so that introduces a new bug because it ends up running all those initial commands twice so I end up updating my canvas twice as often and causes flickering. Anyways to just run the child function and not the parent?

Comment: @Badrush, how about that last edit? Creating a new var called `gc` which is the result of calling `gameCode` once. And then you can call those sub-functions as often as you like without calling `gameCode`every time.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't change the outcome

Comment: some good news. So one of the things I was initializing was the `setTimeout` which then calls the draw function 30 times a second. When I ran my `gameCode` function twice it would then start drawing everything twice.

So what I did was I put that `setTimeout` function in a new subfunction so that when I called the initialization function the `setTimeout` won't run twice.

Comment: is there a way I can access props from within `consolelog()` ?

Comment: Pass them in like normal function parameters - `gc.consolelog(this.props)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Game` class doesn't have a `gameCode` method so you can't use `this.gameCode` inside any of it's methods.

If you imported the `gameCode` inside the js file, you can use it anywhere inside:

```
componentDidMount(){
    gameCode();
};
```

The problem here is that the function `gameCode` in your example doesn't do anything - it only define a new function (locally) every time you call it. It's not an object that you can use to call it's function...

If `gameCode` was an object, you could have use:

```
gameCode.consolelog(something);
```

**but it's not**

You can change the `gameCode` to something like that:

```
export default gameCode = {
    consolelog: function (a){
        console.log("success!");
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

And now since `gameCode` is an object, with the `consolelog` attribute as a function, you can use `gameCode.consolelog(...)` inside your `Game` class.

Comment: I think we're going in the right direction here but to note gameCode() does run some code on it's own. I just didn't include it in my question because it's a lot of code. 

Here is the code and most of my subfunctions depend on these initializations:

`const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = 800;
  canvas.height= 600;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const FPS = 30;
  setInterval(() => {
      update();
      draw();
  }, 1000/FPS);

    function consolelog(a){
      console.log("success!");
      console.log(a);
    }`

Comment: Please update the original question with the code. It's impossible to read code in comments.

Comment: So as explained in the second part of my answer - when you call the `gameCode` - you define a local function (by the name `consolelog`) but that function is not accessible...

Comment: Is there any way to access it?

Comment: Sure. Check my answer, it's all there :)

Comment: Should I put those initalization lines into their own function? Is that necessary or can I just call the parent object to run those?

Comment: You can put them inside some other function that called `init` and just call this function once...

Comment: So I'm in the process of implementing this. Before I was able to call a sister function using just `draw()` when I was inside of `gameCode()` but now those commands are all `undefined`. Do I have to use `this.draw()` from now on for all my functions and variables inside of `gameCode()`?

Edit: looks like I need to use `this.foo()` from now on

Comment: You need to understand the context, and why the original didn't work. I explained it in my answer... Once you understand this - I'm pretty sure you will be able to solve this problem :)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent me from having to add `this.` everytime I want to call on a variable from inside of the gameCode?

Comment: Short answer is "no". Long answer is "depends on how you write your code".

Comment: By the way, you have to export gameCode as a `const` or `var` in line 1 of your solution

Comment: well i replaced everything I needed to with `.this` but now things like 

`this.canvas.height` are undefined probably because `canvas` was initialized in the first `init()` function and is being called by a different sibling function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don;t need to call it with the `this` key word once you imported it. You just call it that way: `gameCode();`.
Second, you are not returning anything from this function, hence you can't access it's nested function.
I think you need to re think the way you expose objects and functions.
For example, `GameCode.js` can look like this:

```
 const consolelog = function (a){
    console.log("success!");
    console.log(a);
 }
 export consolelog;
```

And then import it in your component:

```
import {consolelog} from '../utility/gamecode';
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment, if you need a function that will nest other functions and variables then you can create a `class`;

```
class GameCode {
  constructor(){
    this.consolelog = this.consolelog.bind(this);
  }

  consolelog(a){
      console.log("success!");
      console.log(a);
  }
}
export default GameCode;
```

Then import it in you Component:

```
import GameCode from '../utility/gamecode'; // notice the import for default exports
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is because I have other subfunctions that rely on variables/functions that are scoped to `GameCode()` This is a canvas html game and so I have subfunctions called `update` and `draw` that draw to the canvas and I don't want multiple functions drawing to it.

Comment: then create a `class`

Comment: I don't know anything about classes, how would a class help here?

Comment: that's odd, you are using a `class` in the code you posted :)

Comment: Well that's just because I wanted a class based component so that I can work with props and state. That's as far as my knowledge of classes go.

Anyways, what I need to be able to do is have my component run `gameCode` which then initializes a bunch of variables/consts and then runs some functions immediately. Then sometimes I need to be able to call some of it's sub functions as needed. So I'm not sure if turning gameCode into a class is the answer here.